# Function call(thisArg:*, ... args) first parameter usage in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, function, actionscript, closures

what does call(thisArg:*, ... args) first parameter mean?

Assuming f() is defined in a unnamed package as global function, following is the code snippet:

```
package {
    public function f(message:String):void {
        trace(message);
        trace(this.watchedValue);
    }
}
```

test code as following:

```
public function test():void {
    var obj:Object = {watchedValue:100};
    f("invoking f");
    f.call(obj, "invoking f by call()");//actual result is undefined, but shouldn't be 100?
}
```

Comment: You declare your var as 'obj' but you pass it as 'o' when using the call function... Is this just an error you made while writing the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This param only used in closures and anonymous functions, like

```
var testFunc:Function = function():void{trace(this.watchedValue)}
```

**EDIT:**
in you case it will be

```
package {
    public var f:Function = function(message:String):void {
        trace(message);
        trace(this.watchedValue);
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**
first parameter of call will be this in called function. This is the way to call fauction like a method of object.
But when function is method or top level function first parameter of call() will be ignored. To use first param your function must be variable with anonymous function.

Comment: sorry, What I want to know is Fucntion.call() first parameter meaning, not about "this" keyword

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know *Function.call()* is the same as *function()*, except the fact you *change* the scope of `this`. Normally `this` referrers to the current class, but it could be another class. \

Your test function looks wrong, it should be `obj` instead of `o`

```
public function test():void {
    var obj:Object = {watchedValue:100};
    f("invoking f");
    f.call(obj, "invoking f by call()");
}
```

Comment: This is a mistake, I had changed o to obj.But what confuse me is in f.call(obj, "invoking f by call()"), the obj doesn't be the "this" class